# How do we extract blob data type column's data from h2 database?

Tags: database, blob, h2, corda, data-extraction

We've deployed nodes and posted a transaction from one node to another using corda and the same got stored in h2 database in "NODE_TRANSACTIONS" table.
TRANSACTION_VALUE column in NODE_TRANSACTIONS table is of BLOB data type.

Please suggest how to extract data from this column in a readable format

We've tried extracting data using `resultset.getBinaryStream` in java, but not sure of the supported file type in which it needs to be read. Tried with file types image/txt/pdf etc but none of the files were in readable format.

```
static String url = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:12345/node";
    static String username = "sa";
    static String password = "";
        Class.forName("oracle.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.println("getting connection: " + conn);
String sql = "SELECT TX_ID, TRANSACTION_VALUE FROM NODE_TRANSACTIONS where rownum<2";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
            InputStream data=rs.getBinaryStream(2);
            File file = new File("D:\\blob.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
            while (data.read(buffer) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer);
            }
            fos.close();
        }
        conn.close();
```

Also, please suggest any other way to read the column data using h2 database functions (or) oracle functions

I expect the output to be in a readable format

Answer (score 0):

If you're after having state data stored in a readable format in the database following a transaction, the state must implement the QueryableState interface.

See the docs at https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html and the example at https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V4/java-source/src/main/java/com/example/state/IOUState.java